# WebLogic @RolesAllowed confusion

Tags: jakarta-ee, weblogic

Why does WebLogic provides it's own `weblogic.jws.security.RolesAllowed` contra `javax.annotation.security.RolesAllowd`? The WebLogic one seems to be deprecated, yet the Java EE one doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Weblogic's **@RolesAllowed** annotation differs from that for Java EE in several important ways:

- [Weblogic's @RolesAllowed](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E57014_01/wls/WLAPI/weblogic/jws/security/RolesAllowed.html) has been deprecated since release 12.1.3 in 2014.
- The signature for the Java EE annotation is [public abstract String[] value](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/annotation/security/RolesAllowed.html) whereas WebLogic's proprietary signature for the annotation is [public abstract SecurityRole[] value](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E57014_01/wls/WLAPI/index.html?weblogic/jws/security/RolesAllowed.html). The two are incompatible since there is no **@SecurityRole** annotation in the JDK or Java EE.
- Earlier releases of [WebLogic did not support the Java EE implementation of @RolesAllowed (as specified in JSR 250) at all](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/wls/WSREF/annotations.htm#WSREF180), and only supported [their own implementation of @RolesAllowed for JAX-RPC](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/wls/WSREF/annotations.htm#WSREF182).

However, in conjunction with the deprecation of WebLogic's **@RolesAllowed** in release 12.1.3, Oracle "*[implemented support for selected Java EE 7 APIs](https://web.archive.org/web/20150620163218/https://blogs.oracle.com/WebLogicServer/entry/oracle_weblogic_server_12_11) including JAX-RS 2.0, Java API for JSON Processing, Java API for WebSocket, and JPA 2.1, to enable and support development of such applications*".

So if you are on WebLogic 12.1.3 or later you should only be using Java EE's implementation of **@RolesAllowed**.

As to why the same annotation name exists in both environments, it may be because BEA Systems (the original creators of WebLogic) provided input to the specification of [*JSR-000250 Common Annotations for the Java Platform*](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr250/index3.html), and Java EE's **@RolesAllowed** came out of that, but that is just speculation on my part.

You also mention that "*the Java EE one doesn't work as expected*" but don't provide any details; create a separate question for that if appropriate.